# iPad - How to get crash report

Tags: ipad, crash, report

My app on the iPad (physical device) is crashing and I get this:

Mon Nov 22 14:08:42 ianvinkipad ReportCrash[521] : Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/InterfaithExplorer_2010-11-22-140841_ianvinkipad.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0

Where do I go to read this report? It does not appear to be on the PC. And I am not sure how to get it off the device.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The technical note [Understanding and Analyzing iPhone OS Application Crash Reports](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184) from Apple developer center has a good overview of how to retrieve and analyze your crash report.

Comment: I have the same question. I'd found that link before, but it wasn't clear from the page how to retrieve the crash report. Please answer the question rather than simply linking to documentation.

Comment: I have the same question and I don't have a Mac, I'm running Linux. Anyone has a pointer?

Comment: On iOS 10, go to Settings → Privacy → Diagnostics & Usage → Diagnostic & Usage Data and you should see a smattering of logs and reports. It's not perfect, but should gets you some access to the device logs.

Answer (score 46):

Here's how to read crash reports in iOS:

```
// Upto iOS 8
Settings
General
About
Diagnostics & Usage
Diagnotstic & Usage Data

// iOS 8
Settings
Privacy
Diagnostics & Usage
Diagnotstic & Usage Data
```

Then copy and paste what you need.

Comment: This helped me, too, since reading the logs on a PC is unreliable (my crash logs were not syncing in iTunes as documented).

Comment: it's an empty list on my ipad, even though i have tons of crash reports on it

Answer (score 15):

Looks like the crash reports are moved to my mac after syncing. Found them at ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/

Answer (score 0):

Apple has an [official tech article](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT202100) about it.

iOS 8 and iOS 9

On your iOS device, go to Settings > Privacy > Diagnostics & Usage, and select `Diagnostic & Usage Data`.