# How to read crash report from iPad using Windows

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, marmalade

I am new to developing for ios using Marmalade and Visual Studio, so I need to know how to read crash report from iPad ? Crash report is on location  **/var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/game.plist**
How to read this file from windows ?

Comment: A plist is an XML file, try notepad or an HTML editor if you have one.

Comment: A workaround, to read the log directly from iOS is documented in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15962089/1168342

Answer (score 1):

When you sync your iPad with iTunes, the crash report will be copied onto your computer. You can then find it in the location:

*C:\Users\<Your Username>\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\Logs\CrashReporter\MobileDevice\<Your iPad's Name>\<Crash Log Name>.crash*

Answer (score 0):

You need to sync your iPad to the iTunes, and it'll be available in your iTunes sync folder.
Also I once found a way to read those reports in iPad itself, it was in about section maybe. Do the search, you may find it.

The path is Settings > Privacy > Diagnostics & Usage > Diagnostics & Usage Data

Answer (score -1):

Use iTunes software . it will help for you.

Comment: Very vague answer. Refer Rich's answer instead.