# Windows 8 iOS crash reports location

Tags: ios, windows-8, crash-reports

I am trying to find the crash reports for iOS on Windows 8 but for the life of my I cannot locate them.

This is the only thing I have been able to find with a google/SO search:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\Apple computer\Logs\CrashReporter\<your iPhone’s name>\
```

This file path does not exist on Windows 8, or at least not on my machine.

Anyone know where to look? Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure.. How much it would help for U [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108344/how-to-read-crash-report-from-ipad-using-windows ]

Comment: Turns out it was because I did not have hidden folders and files enabled! Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution, the directory list above is in fact correct. You must make sure that you have hidden files and folders enabled in the Folder Options of control panel.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\nishant.wats\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\Logs\CrashReporter\MobileDevice\iPhone name