# OSX - How to debug distributed builds?

Tags: macos, debugging, testing

I sent my first desktop OSX app out to a small circle of testers today. One user cannot get past the splash screen.

I am wondering how one might debug something like this? Would I somehow write NSLogs to a file? Or does OS X have some sort of utility? I assume I need some sort of logging capability, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your logs to file quite easily (not via `NSLog`, but just plain writing `NSString` to disk via `writeToFile` if you want to). You can also have your logs automatically uploaded to your server if you have one using `NSURLConnection` with a `POST`.

I prefer the latter because it requires little intervention from the testers, and happens automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Distribution builds are not ment to be debugged or else it would have been development build.
You can how ever sync your device with itunes and then get the crash report(if you want to know the source of crash).from appdata.

reffer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242780/ipad-how-to-get-crash-report).  if you want to debug make a debug build with development provisoning. in your case ask the tester to send you the crash report and you keep the ipa or app file safe you will need it to read the crash report.

Comment: this is not necessarily true, bugs sometimes appear in the real world  and it useful to be able to determine why they happened.